# how to run javascript code that included through ajax process

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a `php` page which has lot's of code of `html` and `javascript` inside it.Ihe other page use `ajax` to send an id to the first page and get the results and put it inside a div element. 
Now I want to run those returned codes which contains `javascript` and `html` codes.
How should that be done?

**This is my ajax request to the first page:**

```
       $(document).ready(function() { 
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "showing.php",
        data: "s_id="+s_id+"&submit=true",
        success: function(msg){
        str=$.trim(msg)
         document.getElementById('tabs-2').innerHTML = str;
           document.getElementById("ui-id-2").click();

        }
   })
```

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: @Sadikhasan Showing.php contains javascript codes and I need to run them after putting the codes inside that div.How should I run those lines?

Comment: Use jq `.html()` (`$('#tabs-2').html(str);`) method instead of `innerHTML` property. If using `innerHTML`, you would need to `eval()` js code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197575/can-scripts-be-inserted-with-innerhtml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think event delegation can solve your problem.

Like below:

Use $.on(). Instead of registering events on the element you register on a parent which will not be removed

Ex:

```
$('#tabs-2').on('click', '#ui-id-2', function(){
   //do something
})
```